# socket.rooms returns empty array

Tags: express, socket.io

I have the following on my server side:

```js
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.join('main');
  console.log(socket.rooms); 

/*    ==> []
*/

  console.log(socket.adapter.rooms); 

/*    ==> { '5incJ4hA4tKyJHUjAAAA': { '5incJ4hA4tKyJHUjAAAA': true },
    'stufn-iGnU6NTcXPAAAB': { 'stufn-iGnU6NTcXPAAAB': true },
    main: { 'stufn-iGnU6NTcXPAAAB': true } }
*/
});
```

The socket is added to the room, but the socket.room array is not updating. I am seeing this issue on v1.3.5 and v1.3.2

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Ok, so it turns out because the .join method in socket.js (see module) has an async function my console.logs were called before the rooms were assigned to socket.rooms

Lesson: Use the callback function for .join if you want to get the rooms immediately after the join.