# Socket.io socket.rooms is returned empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have written a simple Socket.io backend and am trying to check now if the socket has joined the room already or not.

According to the documentation:

```
socket.rooms
```

should return a list of rooms the socket has joined. However, for me this seems to be always an empty array.

Below is a quick example code for my server side to demonstrate the issue:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
require('dotenv').config();

function isJsonString(str) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function relayMessage(room_id,msg){
    io.to(room_id).emit('chat message', msg);   
    console.log('Relay msg to room: ' + room_id);
}

function joinRoomAndMessage(room_id,socket,msg){
    //Join the room.
    socket.join(room_id);
    console.log('Joined Room: ' + room_id);
    
    //Relay the first message.
    relayMessage(room_id,msg);
}

//Create the server.
var server = null;
if(process.env.SSL_KEY_FILE.length>0){
    //If the key file is defined in .env, try to start the server in https mode.
    
    const options = {
      key: fs.readFileSync(process.env.SSL_KEY_FILE),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(process.env.SSL_CERT_FILE)
    };
    
    server = https.createServer(options, app);
    console.log('Starting server in HTTPS mode');
}else{
    //If the key file is not defined in .env, start the server in http mode.
    server = http.createServer(app);
    console.log('Starting server in HTTP mode');
}
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
console.log('user disconnected');


 });



socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
  
console.log('message: ' + msg);
// Always expect JSON messages.
if(isJsonString(msg)){
    const msgJSON = JSON.parse(msg);
    // Always expect the JSON to have a room_id.
    if(msgJSON.room_id){
        
        console.log("LIST OF ROOMS:"+JSON.stringify(socket.rooms));
        
        if(!Object.keys(socket.rooms).includes(msgJSON.room_id)){
            
            joinRoomAndMessage(msgJSON.room_id,socket,msg);
            
        }else {
            relayMessage(msgJSON.room_id,msg);
        }
    }else{
        console.log('No relay. The server is expecting a room_id.');
    }
}else{
    console.log('No relay. The server is expecting JSON message.');
}
  });
  
});

// use port 3000 unless there exists a preconfigured port
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('listening on *:'+port);
});
```

Also, below is a console log, when I push three messages to the same socket using this the above code:

```
Starting server in HTTPS mode
listening on *:3000
a user connected
user disconnected
a user connected
message:  {"room_id":"12345","msg":"Test message"}
LIST OF ROOMS:{}
Joined Room: 12345
Relay msg to room: 12345
message:  {"room_id":"12345","msg":"Test message 2"}
LIST OF ROOMS:{}
Joined Room: 12345
Relay msg to room: 12345
message:  {"room_id":"12345","msg":"Test message 3"}
LIST OF ROOMS:{}
Joined Room: 12345
Relay msg to room: 12345
```

Does anyone have any ideas why the array is empty or other ways to check which rooms the socket is currently in?

Best regards,

Olli

P.S. This post ([socket.rooms returns empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29266999/socket-rooms-returns-empty-array)) mentioned that I might have to wait before the socket.rooms is populated, however I get still get an empty array when sending next message to the socket that is already open and joined the room, hence I am thinking my issue must be something else.

Comment: please proive some code

Comment: It it is empty then you must not joined that room.

Comment: Are you trying to use this on the client-side or server-side (this is only a server-side property as rooms only exist on the server)?  We really need to see your code to know what to suggest or what might be going wrong. Also, `socket.rooms` on the server is NOT an `Array`.  It's a `Set`.   Try `console.log(socket.rooms)` on the server-side.

Comment: @jfriend00 Point taken. I have now added some sample code and also console logs in my original message.

Comment: FYI, this `Object.keys(socket.rooms).includes(...)` is kind of crazy.  `socket.rooms` is a `Set` so you can just do `socket.rooms.has(...)`.

Comment: And, `JSON.stringify(socket.rooms)` won't show you anything because there are no public enumerable properties of a Set object.  Do `console.log(socket.rooms)` directly.  It appears to me like you just aren't properly treating `socket.rooms` as a Set object.  Until you look it properly, we don't know what's in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`socket.rooms` on the server-side is a `Set` object.  You need to use proper methods for accessing it and logging it.

For example:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(socket.rooms))
```

will not show you anything in it because there are not enumerable properties on a Set which is all `JSON.stringify()` looks for.

Instead, do this:

```
console.log("LIST OF ROOMS:", socket.rooms);
```

to let `console.log` directly see it as a Set and output it's items.

---

Also, this:

```
 if(!Object.keys(socket.rooms).includes(msgJSON.room_id))
```

is kind of crazy to do on a Set object.  You should be doing this instead:

```
 if (!socket.rooms.has(msgJSON.room_id))
```

and use the built-in capabilities of the `Set` object (that's what it's for).

In reality, you don't even have to check for that as you can just always `.join()` because it doesn't cause any problem to `.join()` something you're already in.  So, just join and then send the message every time.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can confirm that my conditions for checking if the socket is in the room already are now working expected.